# Avoid motion blur in rendering?

Tags: motion-blur

I am re-rendering the Blender open-source Sintel movie. In particular, I am rendering (as a series of `.png` images) a scene where Sintel (the main character) is running.

I am getting motion blur in my `.png` output, but there isn't any blur in the "Render Result" window of Blender GUI. Why do I have this motion blur, and how can I remove it?

I tried increasing the frame rate, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways of setting motion blur in Blender.In render properties by enabling Motion Blur (Cycles) or Sampled Motion Blur (BI) or with Vector Blur node in Compositing node tree. Check which of this is used in your case and disable option or mute node to get rid of unwanted blur.[image]